# Specflow/Selenium tests run simultaneously on same browser (and interfere)

Tags: c#, selenium, visual-studio-2015, selenium-chromedriver, specflow

I have some tests written in SpecFlow and Selenium. I'd like them to run sequentially for the time being. For some reason, they kick off at the same time on the same browser window and interfere with each other. I do want tests to *re-use* the browser window but I obviously don't want them running at the same time on the same window.

I have these classes set up for reusing the browser window:

```
public class SeleniumContext
{
    public ChromeDriver WebDriver { get; set; }
    public SeleniumContext()
    {
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Browser, LogLevel.All);
        options.AddArgument("no-sandbox");

        WebDriver = new ChromeDriver("./", options, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(240));
    }
}

[Binding]
public class BeforeAllTests
{
    private readonly IObjectContainer objectContainer;
    private static SeleniumContext seleniumContext;

    public BeforeAllTests(IObjectContainer container)
    {
        this.objectContainer = container;
    }

    [BeforeTestRun]
    public static void RunBeforeAllTests()
    {
        seleniumContext = new SeleniumContext();
    }

    [BeforeScenario]
    public void RunBeforeScenario()
    {
        objectContainer.RegisterInstanceAs<SeleniumContext>(seleniumContext);
    }

    [AfterTestRun]
    public static void afterRun()
    {
        seleniumContext.WebDriver.Quit();
    }
}
```

An example Steps class:

```
[Binding]
public sealed class LogInSteps
{
    private ChromeDriver driver;

    public LogInSteps(SeleniumContext seleniumContext)
    {
        this.driver = seleniumContext.WebDriver;
    }

    //step definitions here

}
```

When I click "Run All" they both fire up and run on the same window:

[image]

I do not want them to run at the same time on the same window. How can I get them to run sequentially? Using a test playlist is not an option. I'd settle as well for running on different windows but when they behave as they do the tests interfere with each other and cause them to fail. They do run successfully when run individually.

Comment: Which test runner are you using? SpecFlow+Runner, NUnit, MSTest, xUnit?

Comment: "I do want tests to re-use the browser window", is there a reason why you want to re-use the browser? Later on you mention "I'd settle as well for running on different windows", this sounds contradictory to the first statement. Would a solution that has these tests run at the same time on separate isolated browsers be sufficient?

Comment: @mrfreester Want but not need. I would be okay with isolated browser instances.

Comment: @AndreasWillich I'm using xUnit to run my tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was to add the following to AssemblyInfo.cs:

```
[assembly: CollectionBehavior(DisableTestParallelization = true)]
```

This tells xUnit not to run the tests in parallel.

Reference: https://xunit.github.io/docs/running-tests-in-parallel.html

Comment: Very nice :) For the separate browsers solution you could also make the driver not static and set it in the `BeforeScenario` method. Cheers!

Comment: @mrfreester Good to know. This is a route I may go down so I can execute tests simultaneously without them interfering. Thanks!

Comment: @tnw thank you very much for this. I was trying to setup parallel tests with a database involved but to no avail :/ And this helped me at least to run them sequentially.